# JS stops listening to events after sending a post

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I want to send large files and report the upload status. It should be easy, and there are lots of answers on this site demonstrating it. But for some reason it doesn't work for me, not on Firefox, nor Chrome.

I've got a form with files (defined as `<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`) that I'm posting using this code:

```
function post() {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.upload.addEventListener("progress", (e) => {
        console.log("progress: " + e.loaded + "/" + e.total);
    });
    request.open("post", formElement.action);
    request.responseType = "json";
    console.log("Start sending");
    request.send(new FormData(document.getElementById('form');));
}
```

But the minute I click the button which activates this function, the browser stops responding until the whole operation is done and then it just renders the json response.

The console doesn't show any message (not even the "start sending", let alone the progress), and when I inspect the page after sending the post request, it shows as if it doesn't have any JS or DOM at all. i.e. the page is showing, but is not inspectable and non-interactive.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @inetphantom as far as I know the fetch api doesn't provide a way of reporting how much data had been sent, it only returns after completion... So for what I need, I have to use XHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the form, as MaksTech pointed out. Just forget the jQuery part of his, only the following line is important:

```
    e.preventDefault();
```

There are plenty of other solutions you can also modify the action of your form to the following

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); post();">
```

or attach that listener accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Your form submits as a normal form, so you should cancel that like so:

```js
let $form = $('#form');

$form.on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // This will stop default submition so you can do it manually,
    // i.e. as AJAX (XMLHttpRequest)

    // Your function goes here...
});
```

Here's some more information about what's happening here on [official JQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: Why bother using jQuery?